# Android Button Listener lifecycle

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener, activity-lifecycle

I want to make sure my app works as efficiently as possible and am looking into the activity lifecycle. Particularly, I create the Button `setOnClickListeners` in the activity `onCreate`.

From my understanding, android can clear up resources after `onPause` or `onStop`. Does that mean I have to check whether the listeners still exist and re-create them if needed in `onResume`? When user clicks back, home, gets a call, etc.

Comment: why do you think android (gc) will clean your listener. until `onDestroy` activity still has a link on the button and button a link on the listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, Android can clean up resources, but not runtime-important objects in memory :-) The `Listeners` you set will stay there as long as the `Views` themselves. However, things you reference inside the `Listeners` may not be there when they are invoked, so make sure to check whether objects you access are not null :-)

If you need more insight into that, do some reading on how the Java gc mechanism works :-) The `Views` inside `Activity` are bound to its gc tree, so they are safe as long as the `Activity` is there. And when it is recreated, the `onCreate` will be called again :-)

Here you have a quick example:

```
/** This is hand code, it won't compile most probably ^^ **/
public class myActivity extends Activity {
    private DataBase db;
    private Button button;

    public void onCreate(){
        db = /* init db somehow */
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnclickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                db.doSomething();
            }
        });
    }

    public void closeDatabase() {
        db = null;
    }    
}
```

And now imagine that for some reason you called the closeDatabase() method. If the user clicks the button after that, the app will crash with a NullPointerException.

This is of course a direct example (i.e. you are making the db object null in the code) but it may happen automatically inside the system and (rarely) because gc may free something big, like an image.

Comment: So that means that when using a global variable to store something such as a picture Uri, it might actually become null if I interrupt the app for whatever reason?

Comment: More or less, but I mean local fields rather than global variables (you shouldn't use global variables in Android, unless you want to define some constant value). I will add an example to the answer :-)

Comment: That's interesting because my app relies on processing a single image throughout multiple activities and I did it by holding global references to its Uri (since I needed the Uri in multiple methods) and passing the Uri through intents to process in other activities.

Comment: Well if it is just a String held in a static field, that is ok, it is a constant. What you don;t want is holding the Bitmap in a static field which is accessed from multiple activities :-)

Comment: Thanks! Am also reading more about the gc now. I do want to run a last thing by you: is it best practice to `Camera.open` in `onResume` and `.release` in `onPause`, nothing else? Similar for preview, `addSurfaceHolder` callback in `onResume` and remove in `onPause`? I am getting a weird crash when starting activity from custom camera and then clicking back.

Comment: You would have to show me the crash for me to be able to say more, but generally do it like in the example (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html) and it should be alright :)

Comment: It is generally the best practice to release stuff in onPause and re-add them in onResume. Also, keep in mind that onResume WILL be called right after onCreate, so avoid doing things twice ^^